# Loading User Controls (ascx) from other User Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, ascx, webusercontrols

I have a UserControl (ascx) that, depending on the user's credentials, will load another UserControl (ascx).  Currently the control to be loaded, contains a special navigation menu.

I am using this code:

```
UserControl jmNav = 
    (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/client/jmNavigation.ascx");
```

Then, after some more code, I'm telling it to load, like this:

```
    SBarTopWelcome.Controls.Add(jmNav);
```

The problem is, that I'm getting an "object reference not set to instance of an object" error.

Yes, the path is correct - as I tried it like this, as well (in all variations):

```
UserControl jmNav = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("/client/jmNavigation.ascx");
```

This one (and its variants) tells me it doesn't exist.

So!  Any thoughts?

Comment: This one's a classic "where do I create my controls" question. From what event are you calling `UserControl jmNav = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/controls/client/jmNavigation.ascx)`?

Comment: I have a "protected void" that's loading everything from labels to css classes, as well as that user control - it's being fired on pageload.

Comment: Have you added a `Register` line to your markup?

Comment: I've tried that - but on other pages, it wasn't necessary - though, those were on pages (aspx) and not UserControls (ascx).  I even did a "<%@Reference control="path" %>

Comment: Are you able to strongly-define the user control, or are you just using base classes (like `Control`)?

Comment: Just like I did it above....at least, I think that's what you meant by define...

Comment: I guess what i'm asking is is there a class named `UserControl`? Can you access specific methods and members from that class with your variable, or are you using ASP.NET base classes for web controls.

Comment: Ah, ok... I'm using "UserControl" under this "using System.Web.UI;"

Answer (score 1):

One helpful solution is to add `<%@ Register %>` to your parent control. Yes, I know it's in your parent page, but it should also be in your control.

If you do this, you should be able to [Strongly-Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing) your control. For example, a control with a class name of `MyControl` would be:

```
MyControl controlVar = (MyControl)this.LoadControl("MyControl.aspx");
```

If you are able to get the stronly-defined variable, you should have no problems.

Comment: I had the <%@ Register %> in the parent control, as well, but it didn't make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

Inside **SideBar.ascx** add a place holder named **SideBarTopWelcomePlaceHolder**.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="SideBarTopWelcomePlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
```

Then load **jmNavigation** UserControl to **SideBarTopWelcomePlaceHolder** like this.

```
Control jmNav = 
    Control Page.LoadControl("~/controls/client/jmNavigation.ascx");
SideBarTopWelcomePlaceHolder.Add(jmNav);
```

Comment: That's cool, but - I'm using this:
    public Control SBarTopWelcome
    {
    get{ return Page.FindControl("SideBarTopWelcome");}
    }
This is giving me "SBarTopWelcome" - does that make a difference?

Comment: No. As long as SideBarTopWelcome is not null, you can add control to PlaceHolder of SideBarTopWelcome.

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to cast to SideBarTopWelcome control explicitly in order to access the PlaceHolder.

Comment: "public SideBarTopWelcome SBarTopWelcome" can't happen that way.  SideBarTopWelcome is a <DIV> (id given, and runat server added) - this works for other pages - just don't know why it doesn't work here.

Comment: I'm a bit confuse. What is the name of two UserControls and where is SideBarTopWelcome located inside? Normally, we use Panel or PanelHolder instead of Div tag with runat=server.

Comment: "SideBar.ascx" is the one that holds "SideBarTopWelcome" (which is a server side DIV).  The one I'm adding to SideBarTopWelcome, is the "jmNavigation.ascx control".

Comment: Basically, you are adding jmNavigation.ascx into SideBarTopWelcome. It all happens inside SideBar.ascx. If so, making SideBarTopWelcome as Panel or PlaceHolder will solve your problem. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

HA!  I'm such a DORK!  I was declaring the "SideBarWelcome" within a control like this:

```
public Control sideBarTopWelcome
{
    get { return Page.FindControl("SideBarTopWelcome"); }
}
```

When I should have done it like this:

```
public Control sideBarTopWelcome
{
    get { return FindControl("SideBarTopWelcome"); }
}
```

Without `Page`.  Thank you anyway, guys.  I appreciate it.